# Link different properties of MATLAB axes

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to link, for example, the 'XLim' property of one MATLAB axis to the 'YLim' property of another axis? I have looked into `linkaxes` and `linkprop` but as far as I can tell, they can only link same properties, e.g. one axis 'XLim' to another axis 'XLim' and so on.

Using MATLAB 2014b. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I worked up a way to it, it works but it remains slightly clunky ...

The idea is obviously to attach listeners to the two properties you want to link, and update one property each time the other one is changed.

It takes a bit of fiddling around just to be able to attach a listener to the properties of the built-in `axes` object, you have to retrieve the associated `meta.property`. I package this in an external subfunction `findPropertyHandle`.

I made the solution *generic* so you can link any type of property together. Now I didn't program input checks so of course it will work only on *compatible* properties. `XLim` is obvisouly compatible with `YLim`, but if you try to link `XLim` with `PlotBoxAspectRatioMode` you're in for a deluge of red and orange text in your console.

```
%% Demo data and figure
x = linspace(0,24*pi,1000) ;
y = cos(x) ;
hf = figure ;
hax1 = subplot(1,2,1) ; hp1 = plot(x,y) ;
hax2 = subplot(1,2,2) ; hp2 = plot(y,x) ;

%% Find (meta)property handle
prop1 = findPropertyHandle( hax1 , 'XLim' ) ;
prop2 = findPropertyHandle( hax2 , 'YLim' ) ;

%% Add a listener to each property
% no callback yet because we need the reference of both listeners to be part of the callback arguments
lh1 = addlistener( hax1, prop1 , 'PostSet', @() [] ) ;
lh2 = addlistener( hax2, prop2 , 'PostSet', @() [] ) ;

%% group a few things for convenience
pl.obj2link   = [ hax1  ; hax2  ] ;     % axes handles
pl.props2link = { 'XLim' ; 'YLim' } ;   % name of properties to link
pl.listeners  = [ lh1 ; lh2 ] ;         % listener handle
pl.metaprops2link = [ prop1 ; prop2 ] ; % metaproperty handles

%% Set the callback of both listeners
% Have to use dot notation because the 'set' method is not defined for listener objects
lh1.Callback = @(h,e) LinkPropChangedFcn(h,e,pl) ;
lh2.Callback = @(h,e) LinkPropChangedFcn(h,e,pl) ;
```

[image: Linked properties]

---

The code for `LinkPropChangedFcn.m`

```
function LinkPropChangedFcn( hobj, evt, plink )
%LinkPropChangedFcn Links 2 compatible properties

    % find which property was triggered
    changedPropIdx = find( hobj==plink.metaprops2link ) ;
    prop2changeIdx = 3-changedPropIdx ; % because cumsum([1 2])=3

    % disable the other listener to not trigger the property change on the
    % target object
    plink.listeners(prop2changeIdx).Enabled = false ;

    % retrieve property value
    val = get( plink.obj2link(changedPropIdx) , plink.props2link{changedPropIdx} ) ;

    % aplpy the value to the target object property
    set( plink.obj2link(prop2changeIdx) , plink.props2link{prop2changeIdx} , val ) ;

    % re-enable target listener
    plink.listeners(prop2changeIdx).Enabled = true ;

end
```

The code for `findPropertyHandle.m`

```
function [ hprop ] = findPropertyHandle( hobj , propname )
%FINDPROPERTYHANDLE retrieve the handle of the meta.property object

    mco = metaclass(hobj) ;
    plist = mco.PropertyList;
    for k=1:numel(plist)
        if strcmpi(plist(k).Name,propname)
            fprintf('[%s] property was found at index #%d\n',propname,k)
            hprop = plist(k) ;
            return
        end
    end
    % no preperty was found if we are here
    hprop = [] ;
    fprintf('[%s] property was not found.\n',propname)

end
```

---

**Note**
The clunkiness I was talking about is when instead of "zooming out" you use the "reset to original view" menu. This function does not trigger the `PostSet` event of the `XLim` property, so the change is not always propagated to the other axes/property. To overcome that, just after using "reset to original view", right click again and "zoom out". This will not zoom further out in the clicked `axes` (if you were already at the "original view"), but it will trigger the listener and update the second target axes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Don't trust the documentation. I just had the same need: I have a surface z(x,y):

```
x=-10:10; y=-15:15;
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=real( exp( -(xx.^2/9+yy.^2/4+xx.*yy/12)) .* exp( 1i * (xx/4+yy/9-xx.*yy/12+1)));
xz= sum(z,1);
zy= sum(z,2);
```

And want to plot surface and partial sums like this

```
figure;
zyy= subplot(2,2,1); plot(zy,y);
xyz= subplot(2,2,2); contour(x,y,z);
xxz = subplot(2,2,4); plot(x,xz);
```

What I want is to link x-axis of xyz and xxz and y-axis of zyy and xyz.

[image: plot zyy xyz and xxz]

As advertised in documentation of `linkaxes`, this does not work:

```
linkaxes([xyz xxz],'x');
linkaxes([xyz zyy],'y');
```

However, decomposing like this works as expected, at least in Matlab 2012b:

```
set([xyz xxz],'XLimMode','manual');
set([xyz zyy],'YLimMode','manual');
hx=linkprop([xyz xxz],'XLim');
hy=linkprop([xyz zyy],'YLim');
setappdata(xxz,'graphics_linkaxes',hx);
setappdata(zyy,'graphics_linkaxes',hy);
```

If you look at source code of linkaxes, you will find that the code is attempting to `setappdata` on both end of the link, which effectively cannot work, but seems un-necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do that with `linkaxes` or `linkplot`.

I'm afraid you'll have to create your own system that roughly replicates what `linkprop` does internally, which is to listen for events on one axis, and respond to them by making corresponding changes to the other. I'm afraid `linkprop` only lets you do that for the same property on each.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trick: use `linkaxes` to link the `'XLim'` property of both axes. In the second axis, instead of

```
plot(x2,y2)
```

you use

```
plot(y2,x2)
view(90,-90)
```

That way the *x*-coordinate in your second axis contains the *y* data (thanks to the inversion of `plot` arguments) and is seen at the *y* position (thanks to the change of `view`); and similarly for the other coordinate.

So you are basically linking both `'XLim'` values, but letting the *x*-coordinate of the second axis look exactly as if it's the *y* coordinate.

Comment: Very clever! However, I'm getting some funny behavior. Try `a1=subplot(1,2,1); a2=subplot(1,2,2); linkprop([a1 a2],'xlim'); set(a1,'view',[90 -90])` and use the pan tool on the plots. On one axes, the pan tool will move around the axes position rather than the axis limits. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @WillAdler Weird! No, I have now idea. That's funny indeed

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, works in R2019a
function

```
function crosslinkaxes(ax,str)
%
% ax(1)=subplot(1,2,1);
% ax(2)=subplot(1,2,2);
% str='xy'; %link, x limits of ax(1) with ylimits of ax(2)
% crosslinkaxes(ax,str)

for k=1:numel(ax)
    propListener(k) = addlistener(ax(k),expand(str(k)),'PostSet',@event);
end

    function p=expand(str)
        switch str
            case 'x'
                p='XLim';
            case 'y'
                p='YLim';
            otherwise

                error(str)
        end
    end
    function event(src,evnt)
        %src.Name
        disp('lims')
        L=evnt.AffectedObject.(src.Name);
        for k=1:numel(ax)
            ax(k).(expand(str(k)))=L;

        end
        %      keyboard

    end
end
```