# matlab guide, emit event (or signal) when zoom

Tags: matlab, user-interface, signals-slots, matlab-guide

I have a GUI in Matlab created with `guide`. Inside this GUI is a `axes`. 
I want to emit a signal as soon as someone is changing the zoom of this plot.

**Why:**

I need to change the `XTickLabels`. 
When zooming in the `XTick` change and I need to update the `XTickLabels`. It is not possible to hard code the `XTick` values (because you should be able to zoom in and get better fitting `XTick` values).

In C++ with Qt I would simply emit a signal as soon as some zoom factor changes and connect it to a slot who changes the `XTickLables`. 
I'm not sure how to do it with MATLAB.

Comment: You should edit your question and replace `signal` (Qt name) with the word `event` (MATLAB name). Slightly different usage case, but I recently explained in another answer how to attach `listener` to the `XLim` changed event. Have a read, that could get you started: [Link different properties of MATLAB axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204180/link-different-properties-of-matlab-axes/53651106#53651106)

Comment: Thx Hoki, I got it working with the description from your link. Consider posting this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The link in my comment explains how to attach a [`listener`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-concepts.html) to any (*Observable*) property change, but if you're only interested in events triggered by zooming action, you can get events fired directly by the `zoom` object.

Below is a small demo on how to attach event handlers to the zoom object:

```
function demozoomevent
% Listen to zoom events

    % Sample figure and plot
    plot(1:10);
    % retrieve the zoom object handle
    h = zoom;
    % set the callback for 'before' and 'after' zoom event
    h.ActionPreCallback = @myprecallback;
    h.ActionPostCallback = @mypostcallback;
    % Activate the zoom
    h.Enable = 'on';


function myprecallback(obj,evd)
% will be executed BEFORE the zooming happens
    disp('A zoom is about to occur.');

function mypostcallback(obj,evd)
% will be executed AFTER the zooming happended
    newLim = evd.Axes.XLim;
    msgbox(sprintf('The new X-Limits are [%.2f %.2f].',newLim));
```

---

**note**:
This way does not listen to any change of `XLim` or associated `XTickLabel`, but only to the zoom events. If you want to use that method, consider doing the same thing with the `pan` object, as it could also be used to change the `XLim` of your axes.